# Appending to dynamically created divs using Javascript and mootools

Tags: javascript, dom, dynamic, dom-events, mootools

Using mootools I have a 'builder' class that manufactures form objects, dynamically creating divs as it does so.
Some of the form objects are made up of several different objects. For example, a selection object features a textbox which filters the contents of the selector and a button to save the selection.

In this case I want the filter box and button to be located in a div which is appended to the div of the overall form object so as to have a 'wrapper'.

However, I'm having a problem appending to the div of the dynamically created form object.

After the dom is loaded, the 'builder' class is called:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function()
{
builder = new Build();
});
```

Builder creates a new div as such

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var div_id = 'the_div_id_for_my_form_object';

div.setAttribute('id', div_id);
```

It then creates the form object which takes in the div as one of its parameters

```
var form_obj = superSelector(div);
```

Inside the form_obj constructor, this div is saved as a member variable, this.div = div. 
The filter textbox is created as well as the button.

Here is where I'm seeing a problem. (since the issue is the same for both the filter textbox and the button, I'll describe only the textbox case)

The div of form_obj is passed to the constructor of the filter textbox.
When the filter textbox is created, it creates a div for itself

```
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 var div_id = 'the_div_id_for_my_filter_box';
```

When I attempt to append this div to the div of form_obj, I get a js error saying that I am attempting to append to 'null'

```
 var filterBox = new Class({
 initialize: function(name, form_obj)
 { 
   this.name = name;

   this.div = document.createElement('div');
   this.div.setAttribute('id', name);

   document.getElementById(form_obj.div).appendChild(this.div);
  }
```

Yields:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null"

I'm not sure how to get around this. I get the sense that the div I want to append to doesn't exist at the time I try to append to it. However I see no way of generating an event which tells me when it does exist so that I can postpone the construction of any 'child' divs until that point

Comment: `getElementById` only accepts a string as parameter, it seems you are passing a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right. several things you do that are not mootoolsy.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
var div_id = 'the_div_id_for_my_form_object';

div.setAttribute('id', div_id);
```

should be:

```
var div = new Element('div', {
    id: 'the_div_id_for_my_form_object'
}); // or even new Element('div#foobar'); 


div.setAttribute('id', div_id); -> div.set('id', div_id);
```

then appending to the dom:

```
document.getElementById(form_obj.div).appendChild(this.div);
```

why? what are you trying to do? grab an element and add to the div in memory?

```
document.id(form_obj.div).inject(this.div); 
// if this element exist, it will be moved as a child to the new div, not safe
// you really ought to rewrite to:
var el = document.id(form_obj.div);
el && el.inject(this.div);
```

keep in mind this div is not injected to the dom yet at this point.

and so on. read the manual/api - you can always use native js but that kind of defeats the purpose of using a library that fixes things for you.

On a side note, doing what you are doing is not exactly easy, I am currently working with a friend (well, colleague!) of mine on something of a `form-builder` (for mootools, AMD) and it does what you will probably want to do, more or less - input types, groups, infinite dependencies triggered by values (on all el types), all sorts of form elements and custom looks / feels, validators, default values, placeholders, custom events.. Model/controller like behaviour, default values, server side data / validation, persisted per input data (sessionStorage / window.name)

gets created with AMD builder manifests that support versioning, pagination and languages over twitter bootstrap markup and elements and a single-page restful app via hashtags... basically, it is really a big task.

if we ever decide to open-source it (and I hope we can), and ppl have interest, who knows - you can pretty much build things like interactive tests, survey monkeys, quick forms, complex forms, whatever with it... its extendible and flexible. hope we finish it....

Comment: Thanks a lot for the pointers. As it turns out, I had some AJAX issues elsewhere, etc, etc. But I'm going 100% mootools now! Good luck with that form builder, and post some comments promoting it if you ever go open source. I'd love to check it out

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the "form_obj" parameter to getElementById instead of the div itself.  The error seems to be indicating that the div cannot be found in the DOM by the method currently employed.  getElementById takes the id attribute of the target div as a string.

e.g.

```
document.getElementById(form_obj).appendChild(this.div);
```

Comment: Sorry, let me amend that.  form_obj.div.id

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Providing the div id to getElementById in this case yields no error, but the child div does not appear in the DOM. I'm investigating

Comment: once the page finishes loading, try opening your Javascript console and running the selector yourself, to see if the issue is with the selector or the timing of everything:
>> document.getElementById("expected_div_id")

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` only takes a **[string parameter](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId)**. It's returning `null` because you're passing in a reference to an element to the method.

I'd suggest you to get rid of `getElementById`. just use the reference you already have to the `div` you want to append the element to.

```
form_obj.div.appendChild(this.div);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. There's actually a deeper issue with this. I posted this question using getElementById but I've tried using the reference previously.

Comment: I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of undefined.

Comment: But yeah, getElementById was dumb on my part because I wasn't passing a string

Comment: @TomSt.Laurent Try to debug the code using `console.log` or `alert` and see where you're losing the reference to the `div` in the `form_obj`. Or you can post the code inside the `form_obj` constructor so we can see if you're missing something.